# Using RackDAV to expose a webdav directory in a Rails app, how can I map the directory to serve up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webdav

I am using RackDAV, and it's GREAT!  http://github.com/georgi/rack_dav

However, the only way I can get it integrated into my Rails app is to modify my server startup file, which I copied from /vendor/rails/railties/rails/commands/server file!  Obviously not great.   I have this working:

```
app = Rack::Builder.new {
  use Rails::Rack::LogTailer unless options[:detach]
  use Rails::Rack::Debugger if options[:debugger]
  map map_path do

    use Rails::Rack::Static 
    run inner_app
  end
  map "/webdav/" do
    use Rack::ShowExceptions
    use Rack::CommonLogger
    use Rack::Reloader
    use Rack::Lint
    run RackDAV::Handler.new(:root => SOLR_CORES_FILESYSTEM)
  end
}.to_app
```

I want to be able to specify the handler elsewhere, like in environment.rb, but can't figure out how to have the mapping aspect work.  Anyone hooked RackDAV into Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'rack_dav'` to your app's Gemfile and stick this in your `routes.rb`:

```
mount RackDAV::Handler.new(:root => SOLR_CORES_FILESYSTEM), at: "/webdav"
```

Answer (score -3):

You can call RackDAV from metal endpoint in Rails. I can show you example if you need it, but it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'd love to see an example, I haven't been able to get one that would work in other environments where I am not starting using ./script/server.  For example, using Warbler to build a war file.

Comment: @retro: I don't consider the answer very helpful ("I can show you if you need"); basically users ask questions because of "needs".